# Dictionary value list to be printed on same line while writing it in a file

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am new to python and trying to write my dictionary values to a file using Python 2.7. The values in my Dictionary `D` is a list with at least 2 items.

Dictionary has key as `TERM_ID` and
value has format `[[DOC42, POS10, POS22], [DOC32, POS45]]`.

It means the `TERM_ID` (key) lies in DOC42 at POS10, POS22 positions and it also lies in DOC32 at POS45

So I have to write to a new file in the format: a new line for each `TERM_ID`

```
TERM_ID (tab) DOC42:POS10 (tab) 0:POS22 (tab) DOC32:POS45
```

Following code will help you understand what exactly am trying to do.

```
for key,valuelist in D.items():
    #first value in each list is an ID
    docID = valuelist[0][0]
    for lst in valuelist:
        file.write('\t' + lst[0] + ':' + lst[1])
        lst.pop(0)
        lst.pop(0)
        for n in range(len(lst)):
            file,write('\t0:' + lst[0])
            lst.pop(0)
```

The output I get is :

```
TERM_ID (tab) DOC42:POS10 (tab) 0:POS22
              DOC32:POS45
```

I tried using the new line tag as well as commas to continue file writing on the same line at no of places, but it did not work. **I fail to understand how the file write really works.**

Any kind of inputs will be helpful. Thanks!

@Falko I could not find a way to attach the text file hence here is my sample data-
879\t3\t1
162\t3\t1
405\t4\t1455
409\t5\t1
13\t6\t15
417\t6\t13
422\t57\t1
436\t4\t1
141\t8\t1
142\t4\t145
170\t8\t1
11\t4\t1
184\t4\t1
186\t8\t14

My sample running code is -

```
with open('sampledata.txt','r') as sample,open('result.txt','w') as file:
    d = {}
    #term= ''
    #docIndexLines = docIndex.readlines()

    #form a d with format [[doc a, pos 1, pos 2], [doc b, poa 3, pos 8]]
    for l in sample:
        tID = -1
        someLst = l.split('\\t')
        #if len(someLst) >= 2:

        tID = someLst[1]
        someLst.pop(1)
            #if term not in d:
        if not d.has_key(tID): 
            d[tID] = [someLst]
        else:
            d[tID].append(someLst)

    #read the dionary to generate result file
    docID = 0
    for key,valuelist in d.items():
        file.write(str(key))
        for lst in valuelist:
            file.write('\t' + lst[0] + ':' + lst[1])
            lst.pop(0)
            lst.pop(0)
            for n in range(len(lst)):
                file.write('\t0:' + lst[0])
                lst.pop(0)
```

My Output:

57  422:1
3   879:1
        162:1
5   409:1
4   405:1455
       436:1
       142:145
       11:1
       184:1
6   13:15
       417:13
8   141:1
       170:1
       186:14

Expected output:

57  422:1
3   879:1 162:1
5   409:1
4   405:1455 436:1 142:145 11:1 184:1
6   13:15 417:13
8   141:1 170:1 186:14

Comment: There's a typo in ```file,write``` (the comma), but this is probably not the actual problem. A minimum running example including the generation of some dummy ```D``` would be helpful.

Comment: @Falko I could not find a way to attach my files, hence updated the question to help you understand my data, code and the output.

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably don't get the result you're expecting because you didn't strip the newline characters `\n` while reading the input data. Try replacing

   ```py
   someLst = l.split('\\t')
   ```

   with

   ```
   someLst = l.strip().split('\\t')
   ```
2. To enforce the mentioned line breaks in your output file, add a

   ```
   file.write('\n')
   ```

   at the very end of your second outer `for` loop:

   ```
   for key,valuelist in d.items():
       // ...
       file.write('\n')
   ```

---

Bottom line: `write` *never* adds a line break. If you do see one in your output file, it's in your data.

Comment: Thanks Falko. It was helpful. I did try l.split()[0].split('\\t') to remove the newline character but it did not work. I did not know about strip().

Comment: Then, please, format the input data exactly like it is given in the input file (all in one line?) and make clear what your output looks right now and how it should look like. The current description is pretty complicated.

Comment: I formatted the input data, expected output in the above description.
And I used split()[0] not strip()[0]. I was trying to first extract data discarding the new line char with split()[0] and then tried spliting this data with the \\t char i.e. split("\\t")

Comment: Using your code and the given sample data, I obtain the expected result when doing the two modifications described above.